# Fabric js - Modifying groups doesn't change the individual objects

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Right now I'm modifying groups and iterating through each object in the group to change the locations in the database:

```
canvas.on('object:modified', (e) => {
  console.log('object modified', e)
  const target = e.target
  const activeGroup = this.canvas.getActiveGroup()
  if (activeGroup) { // Group has been modified
    activeGroup.forEachObject((obj) => {
      this.updateObject(obj)
    })
  } else {
    this.updateObject(target)
  }
})

updateObject = (fabricObject) => {
   if (fabricObject.id) {
       const obj = fabricObject.toObject()
       console.log(obj)
       update.call([fabricObject.id, {
        $set: obj
      }])
   }
}
```

But the actual objects in the active group aren't changing coordinates, only the group. Is there a better way to implement group modification? Perhaps a better question is, can object:modified be trigged for the individual objects when a group is modified? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the same method fabric uses for canvas export when there is an active selection:

```
canvas.on('object:modified', (e) => {
  const target = e.target
  const activeGroup = this.canvas.getActiveGroup()
  if (activeGroup) { // Group has been modified
    activeGroup.forEachObject((obj) => {
      this.updateObject(canvas._toObject(obj, 'toObject', ['id']))
    })
  } else {
    this.updateObject(target.toObject(['id']))
  }
})

updateObject = (fabricObject) => {
   if (fabricObject.id) {
       update.call([fabricObject.id, {
        $set: fabricObject
      }])
   }
}
```